# MapKit: change background images?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I was wondering if there is a method to change or skin the background image/color that iPhone has when you use MapKit as a feature in an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add image overlays to the MapKit map. Here's a blog post that explains [how to do it](http://shawnsbits.com/blog/2010/12/23/mapkit-overlays-session-1-overlay-map/).